# PHP - HTML - Displaying input form even after submit

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have two input forms and would like the second one to stay on the page even when it is submitted.

```
<div id="first">
    <form method="POST">
        Number: <input type="text" name="number"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['number']) && !empty($_POST['number'])){
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form><br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
        echo "TEST";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

When I submit my first form, the second form appears correctly since $_POST['number'] is not empty. However, the content of 'number' disappears as soon as I submit it.

Then, when I submit the second form, the word "TEST" appears correctly but the form itself disappears since $_POST['number'] from the first form is now empty.

I need to find a way to somehow save the value of number in the first form so that the second form does not disappear.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $_POST['number']; ?>">
```

Then your second form will be changed to:

```
<form method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $_POST['number']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```